# Accessing class function inside of static getDerivatedPropsFromState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm refactoring the deprecated life-cycle method `componentWillRecieveProps()` with its new successor `static getDerivatedPropsFromState()`

The problem that I'm facing with this refactor is that `componentWillRecieveProps()` use a class function inside:

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
  if(this.props.theme !== nextProps.theme) {
    this.changeTheme()
  }
}
```

So when I try to access this function inside of the new life-cycle method:

```
static getDerivatedPropsFromState(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(prevState.theme !== nextProps.theme) {
    this.changeTheme();
    return { prevState: nextProps.theme };
  }
  return null;
}
```

An error jump saying `this.changeTheme() is undefined`.

How should I make reference to this function inside of `static getDerivatedPropsFromState()`?

Any help and explanation on why this is happening will be really appreciated.

Comment: A `static` method does not operate on an instance of the class, therefore you do not have access to anything about the instance except the parameters `nextProps` and `prevState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDerivatedPropsFromState` is used for only updating the state. You should use `componentDidUpdate` in place of `componentWillReceiveProps` if you are planning to do updates.

See https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data-when-props-change

In the blog it mentions:

> The recommended upgrade path for this component is to move data updates into `componentDidUpdate`. You can also use the new getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle to clear stale data before rendering the new props.

So instead of

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
  if(this.props.theme !== nextProps.theme){
    this.changeTheme()
  }
}
```

One alternative is to do this

```
static getDerivatedPropsFromState(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(prevState.theme !== nextProps.theme) {
    return { theme: nextProps.theme };
  }
  return null;
} 

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.theme !== prevState.theme) {
    this.changeTheme();
  }
}
```